# How to cancel AWS Amplify Auth operations such as SignIn, SignUp

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Is there a way to cancel, for example, [`Amplify.Auth.signIn(...)`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/ios#sign-in-a-user)? `AWSMobileClient`, AWS' older auth solution, has something like `releaseSignInWait(...)` that can be used, it looks like. But I am using Amplify Library for iOS. I have to confess that it is not really clear to how Amplify Auth and `AWSMobileClient` modules differ. I had had issues with `AWSMobileClient`, so I switched to Amplify Library.

```swift
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins
import AWSPluginsCore

_ = Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password) { result in
    ...
}
```

I would like to have the ability to cancel this operation, say, if the user wishes to abort logging in.

Comment: Amplify Auth is the current production solution for doing auth with AWS from iOS. AWSMobileClient is an older product, that AWS no longer recommends for production use cases. At the moment, Amplify Auth just wraps AWSMobileClient. While using Amplify Auth, you can access the AWSMobileClient instance via and escape hatch. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/escapehatch/q/platform/ios